# Highcharts - How to show x-axis with incomplete data?

Tags: highcharts

Not entirely sure how to best describe this issue in a title, so here goes.

I'm working on a chart that plots data over time, starting with a single date and adding one piece of data each day.

In the following screen shot, here's what I'm using for a x-axis:
categories: ['Mon Apr 3', 'Tue Apr 4', 'Wed Apr 5', 'Thu Apr 6', 'Fri Apr 7', 'Sat Apr 8', 'Sun Apr 9']

For my y-axis:
data: [4,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Which results in this graph:
[image]

The issue with it is technically only the Mon Apr 3 date has happened. The outcome I want is a single dot for Mon Apr 3 with the rest of the line uncharted.

When I adjust my axis as follows, highcharts hides the rest of the dates in my x-axis and centers the single point:
categories: ['Mon Apr 3', 'Tue Apr 4', 'Wed Apr 5', 'Thu Apr 6', 'Fri Apr 7', 'Sat Apr 8', 'Sun Apr 9']
data: [4]

Resulting in this:
[image]

Does anyone know of how to go about achieving the desired result? Again, just want this first data point of 4 to left align while keeping all of the other dates in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically `0` is a value. You could map the array to look like this instead:

```
categories: ['Mon Apr 3', 'Tue Apr 4', 'Wed Apr 5', 'Thu Apr 6', 'Fri Apr 7', 'Sat Apr 8', 'Sun Apr 9']

data: [4, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```